# Populate group data to a particular series on Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Trying to group tow columns and and populate it as a particular series on highcharts. my code not grouping columns, And showing all data as a single series.

```
$query = $db->Prepare("SELECT class, SUM(marks), DATE(date_column) as 
dates FROM classes GROUP BY class,DATE(date_column)");
$query->execute();
while ( $row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $date = $row['dates'];
    $dates[] = $row['dates'];
    $class[] = $row['class'];
    $marks[] = $row['SUM(marks)'];

    $output[] = array($date,(int)$marks);

 }

echo json_encode(array('date'=>$dates,'marks'=>$marks, 'name' => $class));
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function() {   
    $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
       Highcharts.chart('container', {
          title: {
          text: 'class Marks'
          },

            xAxis: {
                categories: data.dates
            },

        series : [{
            "name" : data.name,
            "data": data.marks
        }],

      });
   });
 });
});
</script>
```

Table

[image]

[Expected output in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whpe7oy8/11/)

data response

```
date: ["2019-02-07", "2019-02-09", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-12", 
"2019-02-13", "2019-03-13",…]
marks: ["45", "166", "78", "64", "64", "627", "87", "352"]
name: ["claas 1", "claas 1", "claas 1", "class 2", "class 2", "class 2", "class 3", "class 3"]
```

Comment: can you post your expected output for highchart?

Comment: @danish-khan-I question is updated with expected output

Comment: where does `class` came from? I can't see it in your database.also can you `print_r($row)` and update your question.

Comment: have your tried `JSON.parse()` your response data ?

Comment: @danish-khan-I please have a look at the class now

Comment: Hi @lipon, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: @ppotaczek highcharts tag has been removed.but i have a little problem with multiple series  populating

Comment: Please provide me with the result of `data` in `$.getJSON` callback function.

Comment: @ppotaczek please have a look at the updated question with data response.

Comment: Hi @lipon, Ok, thank you. Please tell me how would you like to group the data into a series?

Comment: @ppotaczek I want to group class data first and then group it by date, And populate every class data in a separate series with name labels exact like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b9ta20re/1/)

Comment: Please check the result in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x7vzLh2o/

Comment: @ppotaczek its giving this error now `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.success (index.php:432)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: @ppotaczek I'm sorry, You were right i should group data with php and which is the main issue now,My highchart script works properly as i shared link with you before. I need exact this result as shown in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b9ta20re/1/) example, this example contains all the exact data as in my classes table.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can not help you with PHP. You do not have enough data in `data.marks` for three series.

Comment: @ppotaczek please have a look at Jitendra Yadav's answer its now grouping data perfectly, But we are unable to populate it in series.

Comment: Hi @lipon, What is the exact problem? The generated date seems to be plotted correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3d8wuqrz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing your fiddle the expected output you want for HighCharts is as follow:

1: **Category Data**:

- It should be an array of dates.
- Make sure you remove duplicates and order them in ascending/descending order whichever you want, to see a continuous graph.

```
"categories":["2019-02-07", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-09", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-13", "2019-02-14"]
```

2: **Series Data**:

- It would be an array of object, where each object contains two properties `name` and `data`.
- Data should have `n` no of values if your `categories` array has `n` values and each corresponds to same index.
- As we don't have data for each date for each class, we would add 0 there.

So data would look like

```
"series":[
      {
         "name":"class 1",
         "data":[45,0,166,78,0,0]
      },
      {
         "name":"class 2",
         "data":[0,64,0,64,627,0]
      },
      {
         "name":"class 3",
         "data":[0,0,0,0,87,352]
      }
   ]
```

[Final Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emrf0vdc/) which can be achieved by PHP using below code:

```
$arrDates = [];
$arrClass = [];
$arrData  = [];

while ( $row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arrDates[] = $row['dates'];
  $arrClass[] = $row['class'];
  $arrData[$row['class'] . ':' . $row['dates']] = $row['marks']; // to identify for which date & class this marks belong to, we can directly search for index.
}

$arrDates = array_unique($arrDates);
sort($arrDates);
$arrClass = array_unique($arrClass);

// Create series data
$arrSeriesData = [];
foreach($arrClass as $strClass){
  $tempArr = ['name' =>  $strClass];
  foreach($arrDates as $strDate){
      $tempArr['data'][] = isset($arrData[$strClass . ':' . $strDate]) ? intval($arrData[$strClass . ':' . $strDate]) : 0;
  }

  $arrSeriesData[] = $tempArr;
}


$response = ['categories' => $arrDates, 'series' => $arrSeriesData];

echo json_encode($response);

Output:
{"categories":["2019-02-07","2019-02-08","2019-02-09","2019-02-12","2019-02-13","2019-02-14"],"series":[{"name":"class 1","data":[45,0,166,78,0,0]},{"name":"class 2","data":[0,64,0,64,627,0]},{"name":"class 3","data":[0,0,0,0,87,352]}]}
```

Update your javascript code to reflect the above

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
            // Create the chart
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                title: {
                    text: 'class Marks'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: data.categories
                },
                series: data.series,

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Giving this error `Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in` on line 11 `$arrDates = array_unique($arrDates);`

Comment: See my updated answer, you query has date field as `dates` , i used in array as `date`, do update that `$arrDates[] = $row['dates'];`

Comment: I am using php version 7

Comment: Did you tried after changing `date` to `dates`? `$arrDates[] = $row['dates'];`

Comment: let me check it

Comment: update this section. `while ( $row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arrDates[] = $row['dates'];
  $arrClass[] = $row['class'];
  $arrData[$row['class'] . ':' . $row['dates']] = $row['marks']; // to identify for which date & class this marks belong to, we can directly search for index.
}`

Comment: @lipon, let me know how it is working for you. If solves your problem, do accept and upvote :)

Comment: Can you show me output of `print_r($arrDates)` just before using `array_unique`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199408/discussion-between-jitendra-yadav-and-lipon).

Comment: Try fiddle code for JavaScript. Maybe some attributes we have to include to make it work.

Comment: Okay I will check and let you know.

Comment: Can you confirm that the same url is being used to include Highcharts `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js`

Comment: Got the issue. Data array should have all integers `"data":[0,64,0,64,627,0]` but as per your output it contains integers as string `data: ["45", 0, "166", "78", 0, 0, 0]` which is causing the flat lines for classes. Try to convert it to integers either in php or javascript and let me know.

Comment: updated line in php code. `$tempArr['data'][] = isset($arrData[$strClass . ':' . $strDate]) ? intval($arrData[$strClass . ':' . $strDate]) : 0;` convert string number to integer value using `intval`