# Represent an event occurence on a time chart

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, highcharts

I want to represent the time occurrence of an event on a chart.
I'm not familiar with javascript.
Based on the zoom, it could be the number of occurrence for each seconds, or minutes, or hours, or days, ...

I'm using a nodeJS express website, an mySQL database where I have the timestamp of all my events.
A sample of the database:
[image: List of events from database]

The Start and Stop period could be severals days/weeks.

I would like to represent the number of disconnection on a chart.
With no zoom, I might get the number of disconnection for each day, by zooming, I might get the number of disconnection for each hours, more each minutes and more each seconds. 0 should be displayed when there is no events.
In the same way as:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

Before, for a solution which is not dynamic, I've used a mysql query to get the count for every minutes:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as date, count(*) as Count    
from db    
WHERE event = "disconnected"    
group by date
```

But the result is:

```
2019-09-18 00:36    4
2019-09-18 18:14    2
2019-10-02 11:43    2
2019-10-02 11:44    1
```

I would need to get every minutes with 0 when there is not events to get a correct barchart.
Right now, I have this display:
https://jsfiddle.net/pe3ua4t5/3/

Comment: This might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867138/populate-group-data-to-a-particular-series-on-highcharts/57911327#57911327

Comment: This seems a bit too broad.

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yv4ephmu/. What do you exactly need?

Comment: I've added more details in the question, I hope it will help you to understand what I need.